# How can I prove that both this cost functions are the same?

Tags: optimization, optimal-control

Let us starting by assuming that a trajectory $x(k, x_0)$ exists, where k in an instant/timestep and $x_0$ is the initial point of said trajectory. This trajectory is defined by some mathematical model in the form of

$$ x(k+1) = f(x(k), u) $$

where $u$ is the input of that model.

Also, there also exists $x_\infty(k, x_0)$ which is, again, the same trajectory but that goes until infinity. ($x$ is a finite trajectory).

We now want to get the control input that returns the best possible trajectory, i.e., we want to minimize some cost function that as u(k) as free variables.

For that we have the following cost function:

$$ J = \sum_{k=0}^{N-1} \ell (x(k, x_0)) + min \Bigg\{\sum_{k=0}^\infty \ell (x_\infty (k, x(N, x_0))) \Bigg\}$$

where $ \ell $ is a function that returns the distance to some objective.

The system dynamics are defined on the optimization problem constraints, but that's not relevant for this case.

Let us also assume that $x_\infty$ is always a known trajectory regardless of its starting point.

Now keeping in mind that the "min" in the right hand side will always return the lowest cost of the infinite trajectory, i.e., it will return the cost of the optimal trajectory, and we use $u(k), \,k=0, ..., N-1$ to control the first term (the finite trajectory), I want to prove that that cost function $J$ is the same as having:

$$ J_1 = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \ell (x(k, x_0))$$

Basically, and putting the problem into words, I want to show that minimizing the cost of a finite trajectory and summing the cost of the infinite one - starting at the end of the finite - is the same as minimizing the infinite trajectory starting at $x_0$.

For some extra clarification, let me know.

I'm having trouble to do this since my math skill are not that great for the task I need to do.

Comment: Are you asking for a proof of Bellmans principle of optimality? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bellman_equation

Comment: @JohanLöfberg In a way, yes. But what I actually want is to mathematically show that $J = J_1$. Anyway, I don't want for someone to 'solve' this for me but rather to have some tips/guidance on the correct path to do so.

Comment: Isn't that exactly what Bellman's principle of optimality tells you? If I know the optimal cost of going from Hamburg to Madrid, then the optimal cost of going from Stockholm to Madrid via Hamburg, will be the same as the optimal cost from Stockholm to Hamburg and simply adding the known optimal cost from Hamburg to Madrid. I don't see what you mean with not having someone else solving it for you. If you want to prove it, you either re-invent Bellman's principle from scratch, or failing that you read a text on Bellman's principle and learn idea of the proof.